# Can't return axios.all data from getServerSideProps

Tags: javascript, axios, next.js

I want to call three URLs and render their data from `getServerSideProps()`, so I'm using `axios.all([])` like this:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
    const profileURL = 'http://localhost:8000/api/auth/profile/';
    const bookmarkURL = 'http://localhost:8000/api/blogs/saved/';

    const profileDataReq = axios({method: 'GET',
                            url: profileURL,
                            headers: ctx.req ? { cookie: ctx.req.headers.cookie } : undefined
                        });
    const bookmarksReq = axios({method: 'GET',
                            url: bookmarkURL,
                            headers: ctx.req ? { cookie: ctx.req.headers.cookie } : undefined
                        });
    const resp = await axios.all([profileDataReq, bookmarksReq]);
    const data = axios.spread(function(profile, bookmark) {
        console.log('My profile: ', Profile);
        console.log('Saved blogs: ', saved);
    })
    return {
        props: {   }
    };
};
```

My question is how do I return the `axios` data from `getServerSideProps()`'s `return{...}` so that I can use it in the component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you use `Promise.all` instead of `axios.all`/`axios.spread` (they've been [deprecated](https://github.com/axios/axios#concurrency-deprecated)) for this use case.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
    const profileDataReq = axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/auth/profile/',
        headers: { cookie: ctx.req.headers.cookie }
    });
    const bookmarksReq = axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/blogs/saved/',
        headers: { cookie: ctx.req.headers.cookie }
    });
    const [profile, bookmarks] = await Promise.all([
        profileDataReq,
        bookmarksReq
    ]);

    return {
        props: { 
            profile: profile.data,
            bookmarks: bookmarks.data
        }
    };
};
```

Also note that `ctx.req` is always defined in `getServerSideProps`.

Comment: Great, that works right. But how `Promise.all()` works here?

Comment: Both `profileDataReq` and `bookmarksReq` are promises, we just use `Promise.all` to wait for both to resolve (or to one of them to reject). You may need additional checks in case of promise rejection.